# How can I do a rewrite in IIS/web.config that still shows the typed/pretty URL?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, iis, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have an `htaccess` rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/pretty/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)-(.[A-Za-z0-9]*)/?$ /page/pretty/prettytemplatepage/?code=$2&path=page/pretty/$1-$2&slug=$1-$2 [P,L]
```

This works to allow a URL like:

```
site.com/page/pretty/some-pretty-page-ABCD
```

To display the page at:

```
site.com/page/pretty/prettypagetemplate/?code=ABCD&path=page/pretty/some-pretty-page-ABCD&slug=some-pretty-page-ABCD
```

Without redirecting/changing the URL in the address bar. How can I accomplish the same thing in Azure/IIS/web.config?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a Reverse-Proxy implementation. This can be achieved using **ARR** & **URL Rewrite** modules. Refer this article talks on how to achieve this configuration: 
[Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)